# Computing integrals using measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

I am new to Measure Theory, and I am trying to understand how integrals can be computed using measures. I have a very simple question. How can I compute the integral of $f: [0, \infty] \to \mathbb R$ where $f(x) = x$, that is, $\int x d\mu$? I was told that the answer is $\infty$, but I don't know how to prove this result.

**My work**:

By definition, $\int x \; d\mu = \sup\{\mathcal{L}(f, P):P \text{ is an } \mathcal{S}\text{-partition of }X\}$ where $P$ is an $\mathcal{S}\text{-partition } A_1, \ldots, A_m$ of $X$ and $\mathcal{L}(f, P) = \sum_{j=1}^m \mu(A_j) \inf\limits_{A_j} f$.

Can someone show me how this definition is executed, that is, how it can be used to show the desired result?

Note: If this is relevant, I am assuming $0 \cdot \infty = \infty \cdot 0 = 0$.

**Definition**:
Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-alegbra on a set $X$. An $\mathcal{S}$-partition of $X$ is a finite collection $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ of disjoint sets in $\mathcal S$ such that $A_1 \cup \ldots\cup A_m = X$.

Comment: Which measure is $\mu$?

Comment: @rubikscube09 The Lebesgue measure.

Comment: What is an $\mathcal{S}$-partition?

Comment: @saulspatz I added the definition to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Start by finding a partition for $[0,\infty]$ then find a function that is constant over each borelian $A_k$ and that minorizes $f(x)=x$. Then you can find a minoration for $\int f d\mu$.
By the way, the point of measures is not to compute integrals. Measure theory *defines* what an integral is.